# QOpenGLWidget in Qt5.5 rendering QImage file

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I have a problem to render a `QImage` with a derived `QOpenGLWidget` class. If I create my own raw graphic everything works fine but I can't create a proper `QOpenGLTexture`. I see only some random pixel from memory. I tried a lot but it doesn't work. Here is my test code:

```
initializeGL()

    initializeOpenGLFunctions();

    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);

    glLoadIdentity();
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glOrtho(0, this->width(), 0, this->height(), 0, 1);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

    glShadeModel(GL_FLAT);


paintGL()

    mTexture->bind();
    glDrawPixels(mTexture->width(), mTexture->height(), QOpenGLTexture::RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, mTexture);

loadImage()

    mTexture = new QOpenGLTexture(QImage::fromData(image).convertToFormat(QImage::Format_RGBA8888));
```

"image" is a `QByteArray` and works fine in a `QGraphicsView`. So it seems that I am missing something.

Answer (score 2):

`glDrawPixels` last parameter expect a pointer to the image data, you are passing a pointer to a `QOpenGLTexture` that is a completely unrelated object (it probably does not even contain the image data).

What you want is something like this:

```
QImage m_img;

void initializeGL() 
{
  m_img = QImage::fromData(image).convertToFormat(QImage::Format_RGBA8888);
}

void paintGL()
{
  glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH, m_img.bytesPerLine() / 4);
  glDrawPixels(m_img.width(), m_img.height(), QOpenGLTexture::RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, m_img.bits());
}
```

Notice that `glDrawPixels` is not the right tool to do that anyway (it transfers the entire image from client to host memory every time you call it). 
The best way is probably to create the texture like you did and then render a full screen quad with proper texture coordinates

.